# Desactivate scroll event on ScrolledWindow in Gtk with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

I want to desactivate scroll event on ScrolledWindow to keep bars but not scroll with mouse wheel and just with mouse click.
I tried :

```
a = scrolled_window.connect('scroll-event', lambda:None)
scrolled_window.handler_block(a)
```

This code doesn't do the work.

Comment: What do you mean by scrolling with a mouse click?

Comment: I mean scroll just with scrollbars